# Deploying Python script PyInstaller and Flask

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I have a simple python script (myScript.py) that exposes some API for other apps to consume like this:

```
.....
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/myURL")
def abc():
    ...
    return someJSON
```

I used PyInstaller and generated the dist directory. It contains:
myScript* file and myScript.app/ directory

In my dev machine this is how I run my python script:

export FLASK_APP=myScript.py

flask run

and then from my browser I can reach my API like so:

localhost:5000/myURL

My question is now how can I run the generated self contained executable on user target machine. I know this is a trivial question but I can not find it in the documentation.

Is my user suppose to "export" and "flask run" on the target machine similar to the way I run it in my dev environment?